# MySQL suddenly blocks access from particular IP

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm using `MySQL 5.7.40` on `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64)`

I didn't make any changes since weeks.

My websites are on another server. So it's a remote connection.

Since some hours ago my website suddenly cannot access the MySQL server. I'm using `PDO` for that. Another website of mine which also has a remote access to MySQL is able to connect without any problem.

PDO error message is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

Do you have any idea why? Is there something like a blacklist?

Comment: So the current DBs are running remotely? If so, can you connect the DB server with SSH?

Comment: @DreamBold Yes, the current DBs are running remotely. How can I connect the DB server with SSH?

Comment: Out of curiosity; Is this all hosted by you on owned/physical servers in different locations, or some shared cloud-like service like Hostgator? I only ask, because I have some mysql dbs and apis setup with Hostgator and Heroku and have noticed the exact same issue, but it seems to resolve itself after some time and is intermittent. Very annoying. It also affects my automated backups (which I handle on my own from a home server). This only started about 1-2 months ago after years of having no issues.

Comment: What hosting providers do you use? @David

Comment: https://www.delta-networks.de for MySQL and https://contabo.com/de/ für web hosting.

Comment: What does "cannot access" mean? What _does_ happen?

Comment: https://deltablue.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/930480129/How+to+log+into+my+container+with+SSH I was away, but you can set ssh access this way, @David, after that, we can check the server settings like firewall and the like.

Comment: @ysth Sorry, it says: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out`

Comment: @David, did you manage to connect to the server with ssh? Did you have a look at the link above?

Comment: @DreamBold SSH to hosting server or to MySQL server? I do have SSH access to MySQL server but not to hosting server.

Comment: I deleted my answer about the host cache. I think a host blocked would not have a timeout, it would just be denied.

Comment: @David So when you connect the server, you are connected to the MySQL console directly?

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to identify whether *all* connectivity is toast,
or just a specific [Type-P](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2330#section-13) connectivity.

Here's at least three types of connectivity worth trying:

- TCP port 3306 (mysql)
- TCP port 443 (https)
- ICMP (ping)

If some but not all IP transport is usable,
that suggests that core internet routers
have a usable BGP4 route from here to there, and back.
In which case it is likely the distant hosting ISP
has blacklisted just mysql connections,
perhaps to enforce some policy such as a rate limit.

If *all* IP transport is unusable,
then the blockage could be anywhere,
within the internet's core or at the distant hosting ISP.
Add traceroute / mtr output to the question
if there are details you want to discuss.

---

Running tests from more than one source IP network
can shed additional light on the situation.

If you only have access to a very limited number
of distinct locations, then a [Looking Glass](https://gthost.com/looking-glass) server
can help.

---

Note the timestamp of each connectivity measurement. Conditions in the internet can change rapidly. Flapping BGP routes is one of several causes of intermittent connectivity issues.